# ¿Cómo pasar desde un listado a un texto en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tengo un duda con respecto a este algoritmo. La idea es que pueda enviar desde este listado a:

```
<select name="persosa1">se van a registrar
    <option>Juan Lopez</option>
    <option>Alejandro Gonzales</option>
</select>
```

para que pueda ser registrado en un texto que esté en JavaScript:

```
ele = document.createElement('input'); // 5
ele.type = 'text'; // 6 es quien recibe los valores para
ele.name = 'persona' + num; // 6
contenedor.appendChild(ele); // 7***
```

Si desean ver cuál es el problema ejecuten el código para que se den cuenta de cuál es el problema:

```js
num = 0;

function crear(obj) {
  num++;
  fi = document.getElementById('fiel'); // 1
  contenedor = document.createElement('div'); // 2
  contenedor.id = 'div' + num; // 3
  fi.appendChild(contenedor); // 4

  ele = document.createElement('input'); // 5
  ele.type = 'text'; // 6 es quien recibe los valores para
  ele.name = 'persona' + num; // 6
  contenedor.appendChild(ele); // 7


  ele = document.createElement('input'); // 5
  ele.type = 'button'; // 6
  ele.value = 'Borrar'; // 8
  ele.name = 'div' + num; // 8


  ele.onclick = function() {
    borrar(this.name)
  } // 9
  contenedor.appendChild(ele); // 7
}

function borrar(obj) {
  fi = document.getElementById('fiel'); // 1 
  fi.removeChild(document.getElementById(obj)); // 10
  num--;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="ListadoCompletoAgrupadoyParaAgregar.php">
  <fieldset id="fiel">
    Persona:
    <select name="persosa1">
        <option>Juan Lopez</option>
        <option>Alejandro Gonzales</option>
    </select>

    <input type="button" value="Crear" onclick="crear(this)">

  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Francisco, bienvenido a SO, deberias explicar mejor todo tu problema, almenos decir que es lo que quieres lograr, en tu ejemplo tienes un onclick que ejecuta una funcion, que nisiquiera existe y ademas un elemento contenedor, que tampoco esta definido

Comment: He limpiado tu pregunta y he hecho que el código sea ejecutable, pero la publicación es muy pobre. En lugar de poner "_Si desean ver cuál es el problema ejecuten el código para que se den cuenta de cuál es el problema:_" deberías añadir una descripción de lo que se espera que haga el código (sinceramente, no lo sé) y de por qué el resultado esperado es incorrecto.

Comment: No se entiende que es lo que se necesita pero mirando por encima el codigo ya aventuro que probablemente falte un preventDefault (aparte de mas cosas que puedan salir)

Answer (score 0):

No se si es exactamente lo que querias hacer, pero entiendo que lo que quieres es recoger el texto de del selector e imprimirlo abajo.  Te lo he puesto en lista porque es mas rapido y sencillo de ver, pero si lo quieres en input se puede hacer igual.

Trabaja con id-s que es mas sencillo y se ve mejor. Te lo he pasado a jquery ya que es mas limpio el codigo y mas corto.

La funcion borrar sera parecido, intenta aplicar la misma idea.

```js
function crear(obj) {
  var textopersona1 = $('#persona1').find(":selected").text();
  $('#textolista').append( "<li>"+textopersona1+"</li>" );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="ListadoCompletoAgrupadoyParaAgregar.php">
    <fieldset id="fiel">
      <div id="selector">
        <label>Persona:</label>
        <select name="persosa1" id="persona1">
            <option>Juan Lopez</option>
            <option>Alejandro Gonzales</option>
        </select>

        <input type="button" value="Crear" onclick="crear(this)">
      </div>
      <div id="listado">
        <ol type="1" id="textolista">
        </ol>  
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```